# Differentiate between an int and a float value, without any type of type checking

Tags: python, floating-point, int

I'd like to know if it's possible to do this:

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
    """ If both num1 and num2 are ints, return num1+ num2.
        If both are floats, return num1 + num2
        If only one is of each type, return a tuple (num1, num2)
    """
    ...
```

I know that the operation `num1` only applies to ints, and not to floats so i can single out the int-int case with `return num1 + num2`.

I can't single out the case of int-float or float-int without a lot of try-except blocks, and i'd like to know if that can be done in a more simple fashion.

Oh, and It's a **MUST** that i don't use any `if` statements

Comment: **Why** the entirely arbitrary limitation to not use `if` here?

Comment: Even if it's possible, that would be a horrible API. The return value of a function shouldn't be arbitrarily either a number or a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of booleans being a subclass of `int`:

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
    return (num1 + num2, (num1, num2))[isinstance(num1, float) ^ isinstance(num2, float)]
```

This uses an XOR boolean logic operation; if both numbers are `float` or neither number is `float` you get `False`, otherwise you get `True`. `False` is `0` when used as an integer, `True` is `1`. This is an index into the tuple before it, returning either the sum (if the types match) or the tuple (if the types don't match).

If `isinstance()` or `type()` are arbitrarily not allowed either, use `hasattr()` to test for a `int` or `float` only attribute:

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
    return (num1 + num2, (num1, num2))[hasattr(num1, 'is_integer') ^ hasattr(num2, 'is_integer')]
```

or use the decimal point in the float representation:

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
    return (num1 + num2, (num1, num2))[('.' in repr(num1)) ^ ('.' in repr(num2))]
```

Comment: Title says no type checking (which is silly since the whole premise is that the type of the result needs to change if the types are different)

Comment: @Wooble: Well, the premise is terrible.. there is *some* kind of type checking needed.

Comment: Of course the premise is terrible. That's a better reason to not answer and let the OP do his own awful homework, if you ask me...

Comment: @Wooble: there is a code-golf streak in me somewhere that wanted to answer anyway..

Comment: `isinstance` and `hasattr` are lots of strokes

Comment: @gnibbler: *lots of strokes* means what, exactly?

Comment: golf strokes. That's what code-golfers call characters

Comment: Ah, assuming this is a golf code type of question, which is not clear..

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Got rid of the `type()` calls. This is Python2 only (which used to be specified in the title)

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
    """ If both num1 and num2 are ints, return num1+ num2.
        If both are floats, return num1 + num2
        If only one is of each type, return a tuple (num1, num2)
    """
    return [(num1, num2), num1+num2][`num1/num1`==`num2/num2`]
```

---

Just one exception handler

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
    """ If both num1 and num2 are ints, return num1+ num2.
        If both are floats, return num1 + num2
        If only one is of each type, return a tuple (num1, num2)
    """
    for e in (lambda:~~num1 + ~~num2), (lambda:(num1, ~~num2)), (lambda:(~~num1, num2)), (lambda:num1 + num2):
        print e
        try:
            return e()
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: `'.' in repr(num1)` would work too..

Answer (score 2):

Horrible hack, but does 0 type testing (no `type` or `isinstance`, or checking for type attributes)

```
def my_func(num1, num2):
   is_float = lambda x: float(x) is x and 1 or 0
   return (is_float(num1) + is_float(num2) == 1) and (num1, num2) or num1 + num2
```

Edit: ok, to be honest, as @Martijn Pieters says, there MUST be some kind of type testing. I'm just taking advantage to the property of identity of numbers in Python for it ;-)

Also, I **wanted** to make use of the much maligned `x and y or z` Python semantics :-D